# Rotating 2D sprite around tilted Y axis

Tags: 2d, 3d, sprites, spritekit

I am building a sprite that I want to spin along an axis.  I am using SpriteKit on iOS for this, but I'm sure that the question is not really tool specific.

In my case, I have a sprite such as:

[image: unrotated sprite]

and I want to rotate it around the red line as if it is a spinning disc spinning in 3D (even though it is only a 2D sprite).

SpriteKit gives me the SKTransformNode class that allows me to adjust the X, Y and Z rotation of the node.  So I am able to rotate the sprite along the X or Y axis in pseudo 3D.  The following 3 images attempt to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: first rotation]
[image: second rotation]
[image: third rotation]

I thought I should be able to animate the rotation around the X and Y axis in a way to achieve this but I've found it harder than expected.

I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

[edit]

to further illustrate what I *don't* want, here is what happens using simply Y scaling without using an SKTransformNode.  Note that the image inside the circle does not reflect as it turns.

[image: Not working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the art so that the red line is horizontal, then rotate it in Swift on its `zRotation`, and animate scaling along the `scaleX` or `scaleY` to achieve the effect.

For example:

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var sprite : SKSpriteNode?
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.sprite = self.childNode(withName: "//axis") as? SKSpriteNode
        if let sprite = self.sprite {
            sprite.zRotation = -CGFloat.pi / 3
            let scaleDown = SKAction.scaleY(to: -1.0, duration: 2)
            let scaleUp = SKAction.scaleY(to: 1.0, duration: 2)
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleDown, scaleUp])
            sprite.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Spin]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  This is close to what I've done already but have been unable to get the effect I wanted.  I'll have a look at this again now.

Comment: @PKCLsoft Can you elaborate? What I posted (and tried) appears to be what you described. You can make it look even more real by adding some easing to what I posted so that the scaling is not linear in speed.

Comment: NOTE: If the red line is horizontal as a starting position, this will work easily. Maybe later today I can post a gif or movie.

Comment: I have perhaps not provided a good example for the image as it appears almost as if there is a mirror image on either side of the line.  Within my actual art assets this will not be the case, so this trick, whilst effective, will not really spin the internal image as such.  What I could do I guess is that as the yScale hits zero, spin the internal image (in this case, the asterisk) 180 degrees.  That might actually work quite well.  Sorry for not being responsive; I'm stuck in another issue atm.

Comment: I guess I'm still not clear on what you are looking for. My suggestion above does spin it on its axis (the red line), it is not relying on the art asset to be mirrored on the axis. When you get back on this project, if you can provide more info, I'm happy to help.

Comment: As suspected, it doesn't really work as the illusion of the disc spinning in 3D is broken.  I've added a GIF to the question to better illustrate that.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I updated my answer and put a small dot on the art so you can see the spin. I updated the code so it goes from -1 to 1 over two seconds and then -1 to 1 instead of going 0 to 1.

Comment: Gosh that was so obvious, and it's a very simple solution.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! It was fun to help. Often things are obvious _after_ the fact, but not so much beforehand. :-)

Comment: PS: Adding a little easing will make the effect even more real.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be easiest using [SKTransformNode.setQuaternion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktransformnode/2883240-setquaternion) instead.

This makes it easy to express a rotation by some angle around any axis you choose, rather than only rotations around the coordinate axes as with Euler angles. You *can* come up with Euler triples to correspond to any arbitrary orientation, but it's complicated for diagonal axes.

[Instead, you can `init` a `simd_quatf`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd_quatf/2914611-init) using a given `angle` (expressed as a `Float` in radians) and `axis` (`SIMD3<Float>`) to rotate around. Pass that to `setQuaternion` and you're set. You can repeat this each frame, incrementing your `angle` argument over time to make it spin, while holding the rotation axis fixed.

This way, you don't have to do any trigonometric calculations yourself — that's all handled by the `init` function.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'd given up on getting a solution to this.  I'll try this out!

Comment: I've ended up accepting Johns answer as it provides a much simpler solution to the problem and also means I no longer need to use SKTransformNode (which I _think_ will be a performance gain).